# Chrome DevTools - Network Menu Missing from Main Navbar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently using the latest version of Google Chrome, and I've noticed that the Network menu item is missing from the main navigation bar of Chrome DevTools. To access it, I have to click the three dots on the right, and then select "Network conditions" from the popup menu, which opens another menu below the main one.

I have tried restarting chrome, however, this step has not resolved the issue, and I still have to access the Network menu item through the secondary menu.

This issue occurs on all websites I visit, and it didn't start after a recent Chrome update or any specific event.

Here's a screenshot of my Chrome DevTools with the main navigation bar, the secondary menu, and the popup menu open
[image: chrow devtools with network tab on secondary navbar]

Is there a way to make the Network menu item appear in the main navigation bar of the DevTools without having to go through the secondary menu? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some further exploration, I managed to find a solution to the issue I was experiencing with the Network menu item not appearing in the main navigation bar of Chrome DevTools.

To make the Network menu item appear in the main navigation bar, you can follow these steps:

Open Chrome DevTools by pressing F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I.

Click on the three dots (⋮) on the right side of the main navigation bar.

In the dropdown menu that appears, you will see a list of all available DevTools tabs.

Locate the "Network" tab in the list.

Right-click on the "Network" tab.

From the context menu that appears, select "Move to top."

After performing these steps, the "Network" tab will be moved to the main navigation bar, and you will no longer need to access it through the secondary menu.

I hope this solution helps others who might be facing a similar issue. If you have any more questions or need further assistance, please feel free to ask.[image: chrome devtools network tab]